# How do I calculate the difference of two alias for sorting

Tags: mysql, reference, alias

Considering the following code:

```
SELECT SUM(w.valor),
SUM(CASE WHEN w.tipo = '+' THEN w.valor ELSE 0 END) AS total_credit,
SUM(CASE WHEN w.tipo = '-' THEN w.valor ELSE 0 END) AS total_debit,
w.clientUNIQUE,
c.client as cclient
FROM wallet AS w
LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON w.clientUNIQUE = c.clientUNIQUE
WHERE w.status='V'
GROUP BY w.clientUNIQUE
ORDER BY total_credit-total_debit
```

I'm trying to calculate the difference of two aliased calculated values for sorting purposes, but I'm getting the following error:

> Reference 'total_credit' not supported (reference to group function)

What am I doing wrong and how can I order results by using the difference value between the two aliases?

Comment: there's restrictions on where/when you can use aliases like that. this is one of them. you'll have to copy the entire aliased expression into the the `order by`. or perhaps wrap another query around this, and order the "meta" results.

Comment: Your tip to copy the aliasied expression into the order by expression showed my the right way to solve it. Many thanks for your help. I would like to credit you for it, but I thnik that is not possible since this was a comment.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? MySQL normally has no problem using aliases in `ORDER BY` clauses, in MS SQL (not sure about Oracle) you can't use the alias and must repeat the expression.

Comment: 100% sure this is mySQL. Check MarcB and Bohemian comments and similar solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to columns by their alias in the same select expression, so there are 2 options...

Repeat the expressions in the `order by` (yuk):

```
ORDER BY
  SUM(CASE WHEN w.tipo = '+' THEN w.valor ELSE 0 END) AS total_credit -
  SUM(CASE WHEN w.tipo = '-' THEN w.valor ELSE 0 END) AS total_debit
```

Or easier on the brain and easier to maintain ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), order via a sub query:

```
select * from (
  <your query without the ORDER BY>
) q
ORDER BY total_credit - total_debit
```